# Loading a view from a 3D Touch Quick Action

Tags: ios, objective-c, touch, action, 3dtouch

I'm adding dynamic 3D touch quick actions to my iOS app.

I was able to setup the code that displays each action, but I am having trouble finding what code would go within the code below. When the action is chosen, I need the action to open up one of 4 different view controllers within my app.

```
if ([shortcutItem.type isEqualToString:@"addOpportunity"]) {

} else if ([shortcutItem.type isEqualToString:@"bookMark"]) {

} else if ([shortcutItem.type isEqualToString:@"searchGuest"]) {

} else if ([shortcutItem.type isEqualToString:@"myGuest"]) {

}

else {


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

First you will have to create the instances of the view controllers that you intend to show in each of the *if* conditions.

For example:-

> SearchGuestViewController * vc = [[SearchGuestViewController alloc] init];

Next you can present the view controller modally by doing the following:-

> [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
>   Note: You can only present a view controller from within another view controller.

This is one way of launching a view controller.

Read more about launching view controllers in the link below.
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PresentingaViewController.html